# Как на сервисе heroku открыть порт?

Tags: heroku

Я поставил сервер на хостинге heroku.
Настроил web-socket соединение.

К этому серверу подключается клиент, который передает порт на который надо прослушивать. Например 5000.

Вид создаваемого подключения следующий:

https://my-app.herokuapp.com:5000 (Правильная ли такая запись ?)

С порта который смотрит в интернет я проксирую соединение на порт 5000.

На локальной машине проблем нет и порт открывается. Но на heroku этого не происходит. Как можно динамически открыть порт ?

Comment: хероку передает Вам порт, который Вы можете использовать через переменную окружения, свой Вы не сможете задать, для nodejs это выглядит примерно так `server.listen(process.env.PORT);`

Comment: Это я знаю. Порты там внутри лткрываются. Например я могу создать пару серверов на своих портах и обращаться к ним.